# xpath query in c# throwing exception

Tags: c#, xml, xpath

I am trying to extract information from the following xml: [ezb](http://www.ecb.europa.eu/stats/eurofxref/eurofxref-daily.xml)

```
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.Load("http://www.ecb.europa.eu/stats/eurofxref/eurofxref-daily.xml");
var x = doc.SelectSingleNode("//@time");
labelDate.Text= "Data From: " + x.Value;
```

works just fine!
what does not work however and as far as I can tell the xpath-syntax is correct:

```
var z = doc.SelectSingleNode("//Cube[@currency='JPY']/@rate");
labelResult.Text = z.Value;
```

I am getting an exception: "object reference not set to an instance of an object".
As far as I can tell I am not getting any data from my query which is odd as I am pretty sure it is correct. I appreciate any help!

Comment: What is in z before you try and get the Value out of it. If it is null then that's the issue. You don't have a node back from the previous statement.

Comment: Also, don't use var unless you have to. i.e. The type name is a lengthy one from an LINQ result or it is an anonymous type (in which case you have no choice). Otherwise it is just laziness that reduces the readability of the code.

Comment: z is being declared right then and there and should be XMLNode as that is the type SelectSingleNode returns. if it is indeed empty as you suggest then what is the problem with my xpath-query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're missing the fact that the xml file has namespaces. Here's how you can include them in your query:

```
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();

doc.Load("http://www.ecb.europa.eu/stats/eurofxref/eurofxref-daily.xml");

XmlNamespaceManager xmlnsManager = new XmlNamespaceManager(doc.NameTable);
xmlnsManager.AddNamespace("gesmes", "http://www.ecb.int/vocabulary/2002-08-01/eurofxref");

var z = doc.SelectSingleNode("//gesmes:Cube[@currency='JPY']/@rate", xmlnsManager);
```

Your first query works since namespaces do not apply to attributes.

Comment: thx man, that fixed it right away. namespaces do not apply to attributes, might have to read up on that. cheers!